# "d'entre" est pour combien de personne ?

Tags: sens

En apprenant le français, j'ai trouvé que *l'une d'entre elles* peut être utilisé quand *elles* représente ***trois*** personnes ***ou plus***.

Cependant, dans mon cours, *entre* n'est utilisé que pour deux personnes alors que *parmi* l'est pour trois personnes ou plus.

Je me demande donc si j'ai fait une erreur.

---

When I am learning French, I find that *"l'une d'entre elles"* can be used for those who is three or more than three persons. However, in my lessons, "entre" is only used for two, and "parmi" is for more than two. So I'm wondering whether I made a mistake or something.

---

Le texte orignal :

[Dans un speed dating] [...] J’ai rencontré des jeunes femmes très sympas. L'une d'entre elles surtout m'a intéressé. [...]

Comment: *Elles* signifie deux ou plus.

Comment: Oui, mais ici, elles signifie trois ou plus, en contexte.

Comment: Could you give the complete sentence in which *l'une d'entre elles* is used ?

Comment: This seems to me to be an misapplication to French of a now-obsolete (if it ever existed) distinction in English: that *between* is for two things and *among* is for three or more. [See this long grammar note at the Merriam-Webster dictionary website](https://www.merriam-webster.com/grammar/between-among).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "entre" is only used for two, and "parmi" is for more than two.

Are you thinking about

*Entre la peste et le choléra, je ne sais que choisir.*

*<strike>Parmi</strike> la peste et le choléra*

?

This is true in that context, but I would change the rule to

> "entre" is used to contrast two things or describe how one thing stands out in a group of more than two, and "parmi" is for more than two.

as you can perfectly say both

*Entre tous les primeurs présents au marché aujourd'hui, un seul vend des radis.*

*Il n'y a qu'un seul vendeur de radis parmi tous les primeurs présents au marché aujourd'hui.*

https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/entre II B. for first meaning, II C. for the second.

Comment: Ok, d'accord. Mais, est-ce que c'est possible de utiliser 'l'une parmi elles' ici ? Non ?

Comment: Non, "l'un.e d'entre eux/elles" est une expression figée. Voir *Quantificateur + d' + entre* dans la même entrée du TLfi.

Comment: Pas aussi figée que ça : *certains d'entre nous*, *huit d'entre eux*, *aucun d'entre nous*, *quatre d'entre vous, *la plupart d'entre eux*, *ressuscité d'entre les morts*, *le premier d'entre les hommes*.

Comment: @guillaume31 S'agit-il vraiment d'une "règle"? Je ne crois pas qu'on ait une règle stricte qui excluerait _parmi ces deux..._, mais si l'usage ne semble pas aller dans ce sens aujour'dhui.

Comment: @Frank Parmi le bon usage et le mauvais usage, la langue en a choisi un :) Cela ne me choque pas qu'on enseigne comme règle aux étudiants en français que cette phrase est incorrecte. Il y a aussi une logique étymologique et sémantique, parmi voulant dire "au milieu de". Cela n'a pas de sens d'être *au milieu* d'un groupe composé de soi et son unique voisin.

Comment: @guillaume31 Bon, donc en tant qu'auteur je mettrai un point d'honneur à utiliser "parmi ces deux..." :-) Mais dire qu'il s'agit d'une "règle" en français est un peu _misleading_, d'autant plus que l'OP apparemment s'attendait à trouver une règle qui ferait pendant à une règle qui existait dans le passé en anglais (voir le commentaire de Peter Shor). Il aurait peut-être été plus exact de mentionner l'usage.

Comment: *en tant qu'auteur je mettrai un point d'honneur à*... et ce sera toujours incorrect (à moins que tu trouves un exemple probant de cet usage qui du coup ne serait pas référencé par tous les dictionnaires cités). Cela me semble d'ailleurs assez stérile de buter sur cet aspect. Des milliers de règles - d'usage, de grammaire, d'orthographe etc. - sont enseignées aux étudiants chaque jour. C'était le sens de l'emploi de *rule* par l'OP.

Comment: @guillaume31 C'est le vieux débat entre les _règles_ et _l'usage_. _Incorrect_ est un peu trop fort ici, et les ngrams retournent quelques exemples pour _parmi ces deux_ (je n'ai pas vérifié en profondeur). https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=parmi+ces+deux%2C+parmi+les+deux&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=fr-2019&smoothing=3

Comment: @Guillaume31 *Parmi* signifie peut-être *au milieu de* mais il me semble que ce n'est pas très différent du sens de *entre*. On trouve aussi des centaines d'occurrences de *parmi les deux* et *parmi ces deux*, dont celle-ci de Molière: *Vous savez que je suis engagée de parole à ne rien prononcer là-dessus ; et **parmi ces deux princes** votre inclination ne peut point se tromper , et faire un choix qui soit mauvais*. *Les amants magnifiques*, 1670.

Answer (score 1):

"L'un d'entre eux"/"L'une d'entre elles" literally means "one of them" and could be used anytime you could say that.

> J’ai rencontré deux jeunes femmes très sympas. L'une d'entre elles surtout m'a intéressé.

> I met two interesting young gals. One of them particularly made me interested.

It also works with other (plural) pronouns:

> Personne n'aurait pu entrer cette nuit: le coupable est l'un d'entre nous.

> Nobody could have come in that night: the culprit is one of us.

It can also work to speak about more than one thing in a set of more things:

> En trichant, j'ai vu les cartes de mon adversaire: deux d'entre elles sont des trèfles.

> By cheating, I have seen my opponent's cards: two of them are clubs.

Comment: Yes, it woks for 2 ,3 or more : *Il y avait deux jumelles dans la salle. L'une d'entre elles était blonde. Cet été-là naquirent les triplés. L'un d'entre eux pesait moins de deux kilos*.